# Python sort partial list items

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have parsed a tsv file and have this structure:

```
[['x1','y1','x2','y2'],
[1,1,0,80],
[.95,1,.05,70],
[.93,1,.1,65],
…
]
```

My `x1` values are in descending order; starting from `1` going down to `0`. My `x2` values are in ascending order; starting from `0` going up to `1`. I need both to be in ascending order. I can't just flip the list or else `x2` will be in descending order. Also, note that `x1` and `y1` are pairs, so whatever we do to `x1` we must do to `y1` to make sure the data is still preserved.

I have omitted my attempt out of shame, but if everyone promises not to laugh, what I tried was adding a `-i` to get the nth last item from my original list. `raw_data` is the data structure seen above.

```
new_list = [[raw_data[2][-i], raw_data[3][-i]] for i in raw_data
```

Unfortunately, that did not work.

**Question:** How can I write a list comprehension such that my `x1` (and the corresponding `y1` values) are in ascending order?

Comment: It's better to add your previously attempted code so that we under stand your intentions better which consequently makes you get better answers.

Comment: In order to avoid misunderstandings, please always include the expected output/result for your sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that when comparing tuples, the comparison is based on the first element -- and for equal first elements, the second element is compared. With that in mind, you could first massage your list of lists into a list of tuples associating each 'x1' value with the respective 'y1' value, and then getting the sorted list:

```
>>> lst = [['x1','y1','x2','y2'],[1,1,0,80],[.95,1,.05,70],[.93,1,.1,65]]
>>> sorted((x1, y1) for x1, y1, x2, y2 in lst[1:])
[(0.93, 1), (0.95, 1), (1, 1)]
```